# How to bind a calculated field to a stripe feed as payment amount?

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

i'm using **Stripe Add-On** over **Gravity Forms** to perform payments. A user can even use to pay one shot the whole amount or make it split down to 4 payments.

Let's say the form total amount is 1 000 $. We give the opportunity to the user to go on **4 payments** of 250 $ instead. The whole thing is in place, we used Gravity Forms little code to stop Stripe subscription after 4 payment process. (https://docs.gravityforms.com/cancel-stripe-subscription-payments/).

I was able to put down a number type field to calculate the total amount (1000) divided by 4 (250)... but the Stripe feed **only accept product field or Total Field** as payment amount. And if I use product field to do the calculation, it simply add the calculated amount (250 $) to the form total (1000 $), so whe're now up to 1250 $.

Any Idea to tweak a little something by code or workaround using fields only ?

This is the last step to the whole project, ... ouff !
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it.

Two ways :

1- **By code** using gform_submission_data_pre_process_payment. 
- You could change the payment amount. https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_submission_data_pre_process_payment/.
- Than work with number field (calculation) to show the amount to the end user.

2- **Using Product field** as Calculation (with CSS Trick).
- Do your math thing like : {Total} / 4
- Do **NOT** disable Qty option (otherwise it gonna add the amount to your total since he thinks Qty = 1).
- On the front end, you need to hide the qty since you don't want the end-user to change it (now the system thinks the **qty = 0 and that's the trick**) : 

**css trick** 
(all forms within your site will be affected.
You could go deeper within CSS to specify field with ID or even form_id=>field_id)

```
.ginput_quantity, .ginput_quantity_label {
    display:none;
}
```

[Stripe Feed - Subscription type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkfZ2.png)
[Front-end user form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8rnP.png)